# arcmap envelope coordinates from webbrowser tool

Tags: arcmap, web-mapping, coordinate-system, php

So I have my own php file with textfields which I run in my add in. Now I want to get the variables from the textfields and automatically give the value of the textfields to my `env.PutCoords(x,y,x,y)` 
How do I do this?